# How can I take certain inputs from a user on a website and pass those values as specific parameters in my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, user-input

I have a function that works properly in the console when I run it:

```
function sumArray(arr) {

      var res = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        res += arr[i];



    }

        return res;

}


function totalLength(thk, ...dim) {

    if (thk === 7) {

       thk = .1793;

    }

     if (thk === 10) {

       thk = .1345;

    }

     if (thk === 11) {

       thk = .1196;

    }

     if (thk === 12) {

       thk = .1046;

    }

     if (thk === 13) {

       thk = .0897;

    }

     if (thk === 14) {

       thk = .0747;

    }

     if (thk === 16) {

       thk = .0598;

    }

     if (thk === 18) {

       thk = .0478;

    }

     if (thk === 19) {

       thk = .0418;

    }

     if (thk === 20) {

       thk = .0359;

    }

     if (thk === 22) {

       thk = .0299;

    }

     if (thk === 24) {

       thk = .0239;

    }

     if (thk === 26) {

       thk = .0179;

    }

     if (thk === 28) {

       thk = .0149;

    }

    var bendDeduction = (arguments.length - 2) * (1.55 * thk);

    var dimSum = sumArray(dim);

    var lengthMinusBend = dimSum - bendDeduction;

    return lengthMinusBend;

    
}
```

But I am having a lot of trouble setting up boxes for number inputs on a website to accept user inputs and pass them as the parameters in the totalLength() function.

For the thk parameter I set up this box:

```
<label for="thk">Thickness or Gauge:</label>
      <input type="number" id="thk" name="thk">
```

For the ...dim parameter I set up 8 boxes for up to 8 bends like this:

```
  <label for="bend1" id="1" name="bend1">Bend 1:</label>
      <input type="number" name="bend1">
```

Then I just want to return the output either as an alert when I press a submit button.

I am brand new to everything and in the process of learning but I saw an opportunity for a solution at my current job and I have been trying for a while now to just get everything right. thank you for any help

Comment: define an array which maps thk values , then you can replace your long list of if's with single line

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are thinking about this a bit backwards. You should be setting up event handling callback functions that can run at specific moments in time, like when a user supplies input to a form field or when a key is pressed. At those moments, you can get the data from the form fields directly and don't need them passed to functions.

Here's an example (see inline comments for details):

```js
// Get references to inputs you'll need later
const input1 = document.getElementById("num1");
const input2 = document.getElementById("num2");

// Set up an input event handler for the form field
// The input event fires whenever the field recieves
// input (could be through direct keyboard data entry
// or through a paste operation...doesn't matter how
document.getElementById("num1").addEventListener("input", processInput);
document.getElementById("num2").addEventListener("input", processInput);

function processInput(){
  // There's no need to pass anything to this funciton because
  // it can just get the values it needs at this point in time
  console.clear();
  console.log("num1 x num2 = ", num1.value * num2.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1" value="1">
<input type="number" id="num2" value="1">
```

Also, your long `if` statement is unnecessary. If you define two arrays (one for the possible inputs and one for the corresponding possible outputs), you can just find the index of the input in the first array and then get the item at that same index in the second array.

Here's an example of that:

```js
// Two arrays: one for the inputs and one for the corresponding outputs
let thkIn = [7,10,11,12,13,14,16,18,19,20,22,24,26,28];
let thkOut = [.1793,.1345,.1196,.1046,.0897,.0747,.0598,.0478,.0418,.0359,.0299,.0239,.0179,.0149];

// Let's say the input was 16....
// Get the index position in the first array of where 16 is:
let inPosition = thkIn.indexOf(16); // 6

// Get the corresponding output
console.log(thkOut[inPosition]);
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. What is processInput() doing there?

Comment: @AndrewCurto It's just doing some basic math with both of the inputs when either of their values change. if you run it, you'll see messages in the console as you change the values.

Comment: Sorry Im still a little confused at this. Would it be easier to just create a form and add an event listener to that? so when I hit submit, the values that are in there will be plugged in as parameters to the equation?

Comment: @AndrewCurto I'm not sure you are clear on what a `submit` event is/does. When a `form` is submitted, the browser is redirected to the URL specified in the `form` element's `action` attribute via the `method` (post or get) specified in the `method` attribute of the `form`. This is not usually a time to do additional page processing (although form validation and other data "massaging" is done here).  Is a redirect to a URL where the form data is processed by the server what you are intending to happen?

Comment: you are right i am not clear on that. what i want the page to do is just take the numbers (which are dimensions of a part that is bend, so the bends vary) and use them as the parameters in the function that runs. I know I have to addEventListener but im not clear on what processInput() does after that and how just adding this will plug in to my thk and ...dim array parameters. I am going to research as much as i can

Comment: @AndrewCurto Ok, you shouldn't be using a `submit` button then. Use `input type="button"` and set up a `click` event handler just like I did for it, but with the event being `click` instead of `input`. The `processInput()` function that I'm using is just for demonstration. You can register any function you want as the handler and do anything you like in that handler. The point is that you don't have to pass arguments to the function, just get references to the element(s) that you'll need to work with (as I did) and access their `.value` at that point in time.

Comment: so when i hit click, what exactly is supposed to  happen to make the thickness input to go into the thk paramter of my totalLength(thk, ...dim) function, as well as however many dimensions are entered as the remaining ...dim parameters?

can i add an event listener that on the click goes into maybe a function that collects the thk value and lets it be the thk parameter in the totalLength function as well as all the bend dimensions into an array used as the ...dim parameter?

Comment: @AndrewCurto Again, you don't need parameters. Inside your function just reference the element and its value.. .just as I'm showing as an example above. If, within that event handling function, you then want to call another function that does take a parameter, just pass that same value you got directly from the element.

Comment: @AndrewCurto Do you see in my example above, that I'm getting references to the input elements right away, but later, in the `input` event, I'm just accessing their `.value`? There's no need to pass any arguments into the `processInput` function - - just get the values as you need them.

Comment: document.getElementById("num1").addEventListener("click", processInput);

what is the processInput put here and why is it not processInput() ? Would this just be my totalLength() function? im confused at why its written this way

Comment: The second argument to [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is a function ***reference***. You're telling the system what function to run when the event occurs. You do not put `()` after the function name because that wouldn't be a function ***reference***, that would be you invoking (running) the function right away. Yes, you would replace `processInput` with whatever function name you want called when the event happens.

Comment: okay this is starting to make more sense. so the user puts in one dimension for the thickness, and lets say 4 dimensions for the bends. the event listener passes these values, which are the constants referenced above, into my reference function on the "click" event.  then my function is executed  (with nothing entered as parameters)  should have the values inputted correctly, because inside that function i would have my formula executed referencing the constants from the beginning. is that right?

Comment: @AndrewCurto Well, sort of. There is no "passing" of anything. You simply go get the values that are in the elements at the time you need them. The references to the elements are made ahead of time, so that when you need to access them, the system already knows what elements you are talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229585/discussion-between-andrew-curto-and-scott-marcus).

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/disingh123/qf6x4r1c/4/

```
 <form class="" id='my-form'>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="thk">Thickness or Gauge:</label>
            <input type="number" id="thk" name="thk">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="thk">Bend 1:</label>
            <input type="number" id="thk" name="bend1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="thk">Bend 2:</label>
            <input type="number" id="thk" name="bend2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="thk">Bend 3:</label>
            <input type="number" id="thk" name="bend3">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="thk">Bend 4:</label>
            <input type="number" id="thk" name="bend4">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="thk">Bend 5:</label>
            <input type="number" id="thk" name="bend5">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="thk">Bend 6:</label>
            <input type="number" id="thk" name="bend6">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="thk">Bend 7:</label>
            <input type="number" id="thk" name="bend7">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="thk">Bend 8:</label>
            <input type="number" id="thk" name="bend8">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const formRef = document.getElementById('my-form');
    formRef.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(event.target);
        const formObject = Object.fromEntries(formData);
        const bendArray = []
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(formObject)) {
            if (key.indexOf('bend') !== -1) {
                bendArray.push(Number.parseInt(value))
            }
        }
        alert(totalLength(Number.parseInt(formObject['thk']), bendArray))
    });
});

function sumArray(arr) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        res += arr[i];
    }
    return res;
}


function totalLength(thk, dim) {
    if (thk === 7) {
        thk = .1793;
    }
    if (thk === 10) {
        thk = .1345;
    }

    if (thk === 11) {
        thk = .1196;
    }

    if (thk === 12) {
        thk = .1046;
    }

    if (thk === 13) {
        thk = .0897;
    }

    if (thk === 14) {
        thk = .0747;
    }

    if (thk === 16) {
        thk = .0598;
    }

    if (thk === 18) {
        thk = .0478;
    }

    if (thk === 19) {
        thk = .0418;
    }

    if (thk === 20) {
        thk = .0359;
    }

    if (thk === 22) {
        thk = .0299;
    }

    if (thk === 24) {
        thk = .0239;
    }

    if (thk === 26) {
        thk = .0179;
    }

    if (thk === 28) {
        thk = .0149;
    }

    var bendDeduction = (arguments.length - 2) * (1.55 * thk);
    var dimSum = sumArray(dim);
    var lengthMinusBend = dimSum - bendDeduction;
    return lengthMinusBend;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am having trouble getting that to work when I click on the link. Also, its only accepting whole numbers as inputs. And when I hit enter, I am getting NaN

Comment: @AndrewCurto I have updated the demo link to accept number upto two decimal places. Please check now. Also, you need to add validations that user fills values in all textboxes otherwise you will get NaN.

Comment: I figured out the step attribute to add, but when I run this, the number of bends will vary. It won't always be 8, but up to 8 bends. And when I do run it with 8 bends, it seems to only give me a whole number as an alert

Comment: also i noticed all your labels say for: "thk" and all your id's are the same. is there a reason for that? cause i can't make sense of it

Comment: `It won't always be 8, but up to 8 bends.` - How you want to control this count? I mean how would the user tell that what should be total bend count?

Comment: the user knows the total bend count when they are entering the numbers in. basically, this takes dimensions of a part that is bent x number of times, inputs the dimensions, and subtracts the bend deduction to give the user the total length of the part without the bend, because parts elongate on bending.

Answer (score -1):

On pressing submit button you can call a function using onClick event of JS.

```
function onSubmit() {
  // And get Value of the input fields using 
  
  let thk = document.getElementById('thk');
  
  // like these the values can be accessed. and passed on to the other functions
  // ........
  
  let getTotalLength = totalLength(thk,...);

}
```

**Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp**

Comment: If you have a submit button (which page interaction forms won't have), you should set up a `submit` event handler on the `form`, rather than a `click` handler on the `button`. Also, W3 Schools is well-known to have outdated, incomplete, or just plain incorrect info. Use Mozilla Developer Network instead.